# A property of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily with 1) containing a non-zero element $a$ with $a^4 + a = 2a^3$. Is it true that $R$ must have at least one non-zero idempotent element?

Comment: If $a^2=a$ you are done, take that one. Otherwise prove that $a^2-a$ (which is non-zero) is idempotent using the relation given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a^4-2a^3+a^2=a^2-a$, i.e. $(a^2-a)^2=a^2-a$. So $a^2-a$ is an idempotent, and if it equals 0, then $a^2=a$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(a^2-a)^2 = a^2-a$. ${}$

> Now consider two cases: $a^2-a = 0$ and $a^2-a \ne 0$.